# How do get void pointers working as desired below in the description?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am trying to implement a stack in C program.
This is the header file of my program, `Stack.h`.

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H


typedef struct node {

    void *data;
    struct node *next;
}Stack;


void push(Stack **, void *);
void *pop(Stack **);
void *peek(Stack **);

#endif
```

This is my implementation of the functions, in `Stack.c` file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Stack.h" 

void push(Stack **TOP, void *data) {

    Stack *PTR;

    PTR = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if(!PTR) return;

    PTR->data = data;
    PTR->next = *TOP;
    *TOP = PTR;
}

void *pop(Stack **TOP) {

    Stack *PTR;
    void *data;
    PTR = *TOP;

    *TOP = PTR->next;
    data = PTR->data;
    free(PTR);

    return data;
}

void *peek(Stack **TOP) {

    Stack *PTR;
    PTR = *TOP;

    return PTR->data;
}
```

This is my `main.c` file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Stack.h"

int main() {

    int count;
    Stack *TOP = NULL;


    for(count = 0; count < 100; count += 10)
        push(&TOP, &count);

    while(TOP != NULL)
        printf("%d\n", *(int *)pop(&TOP));
}
```

This prints out `100` 11 times like this:

```
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
```

while it should have printed this:

```
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10
0
```

Well, I know why this is happening. Its because we are passing the address where the `count` variable is stored regardless of the value it contains. Hence, we get the last value pushed in the stack 10 times.

But when I modify my `main.c` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Stack.h"

int main() {

    Stack *TOP = NULL;
    int a = 5;
    char b = 'A';
    float c = 15.98;
    long d = 225678460;


    push(&TOP, &a);
    push(&TOP, &b);
    push(&TOP, &c);
    push(&TOP, &d);

    printf("%ld\n", *(long *)pop(&TOP));
    printf("%f\n", *(float *)pop(&TOP));
    printf("%c\n", *(char *)pop(&TOP));
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)pop(&TOP));
}
```

then I get the output as desired as:

```
225678460
15.980000
A
5
```

How should I modify my 1st `main.c` in order to get the desired output as in 2nd `main.c` ?

Thanks in advance for the biggest help of my programming life. This is my college project.

Comment: I did it purposely as the first data pushed in the stack must have `NULL` in it's reference part. That's no mistake.

Comment: Why would it even care about the value in `*TOP`? `*TOP` is a pointer here. just has to be referenced to a new location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your stack holds *pointers* to values, and not literal values, you have to hold those values at *different* addresses. If you use just one variable in a loop, you are storing all those values successively into the *same* address. So all the nodes on your stack are all pointing to that one address.

To get around this, you can allocate memory on the heap for each value. Like this:

```
for(count = 0; count < 100; count += 10) {
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = count;
    push(&TOP, (void*)ptr);
}
```

In your case, you are exiting immediately after printing the values on the stack, so you can get away without `free`ing the allocated memory. It will all be freed when the program exits. But if actually doing something like this in a real program, make sure to `free` the memory allocated for each value when you don't need it any more. OR, more realistically, if what you want is a stack of integers, just make each node hold an `int` rather than a void pointer.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I know that I am pointing to the same address where the variable `count` is stored, everytime, as I mentioned in the description. Is there no way I can do it without using `malloc()`? Coz I would re-use my Stack program and I dont want to allocate memory again and again everytime I use it. And thanks for suggesting to hold `int` rather than `void *`. But I would like to keep it generic. Any workaround, any thing would do apart from allocating memory manually. Can I, by any means, create memory in the `push()` function rather that the loop itself?

Comment: You can do it in `push`, by copying the data. You would need a third parameter to tell `push` how many bytes to malloc and copy.

Comment: Oh hey! Thats an amazing Idea. But that would again be a bit complex for the re-users of my program. Coz that's not actual `push()`. But anyways. I will go with this, for now. Thanks :)

Comment: This is not working though, as `void *` are not assignable. :(

Comment: @BakchodBhosdiwala, then just cast the `int*` to `void*` at the needed place. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Please note that casting is *required* to do anything useful with a `void*`. The C standard guarantees that a `void*` is big enough to store any other type of pointer, so you don't need to worry that casting back and forth to a different type of pointer will make the code non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

you problem is that what stack is holding is the address of count. you are initializing your stack with an address and not a value. *(PTR->data) = *data; i think should work now it should  update a value in data field and not an address. you will need to allocate memory for data field now too...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But `void *` is not assignable. This is not possible as per my knowledge. Any other workaround? :)

Comment: Casting won't keep it generic. I want to keep it generic. Thanks.